# Integer division of Linear Polynomials

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

The problem we're trying to solve today is a fairly standard root finding problem, that's complicated by rounding errors in how the function is computed. All quantities in this problem are stored as arbitrarily long integers, and division is integer division.

The function of interest is $$f(p_1, ...., p_n) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n L_iC_ip_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n D_ipi }$$

However, due to some querks in the code that computes $f(\vec{p})$, instead of the numerator being computable directly, it instead computes the weighted averages of L, then applies to to the $\sum C_ip_i$. So instead we have:
$$\frac{\frac{\sum L_iC_ip_i}{\sum C_ipi}*\sum Cip_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n D_ipi}$$

Suppose we have a starting vector $\vec{P}$ and constant $h$.
For each component $p_i$, perturb that component holding the others constant to find the new vector $\vec{P^i}$ with coordinate $p_i$:
$$max(p_i) s.t. f(\vec{P^i}) < h$$

If we use the first definition of the function, this has a fairly trivial closed form solutions that approximates the answer to the second definition (you can pick which side to go on by taking the derivative):

$$p_j = \frac{\sum_{i!=j} (aD_ip_i - L_iC_ip_i)}{LjCj - D_ja}$$

The problem I face is that the second definition introduces a non-trivial rounding error, as the $L_i$ coefficients are small compared to $C_ip_i$. Whereas the errors in using the first definition are $O(10^{-18})$, with the second they are $O(10^{-5})$ (coefficient L are general around $10^{5}$)

In order to account for this, I need to understand the intervals of $p_i$ where the weighted average of $\vec{L}$ is constant due to rounding error (recall all quantities are integers, and we perform integer division). Knowing when these step changes occur, I'm able to compute the weighted average over that interval, and apply a similar formula to the closed form above.

My interest / question here is computing these intervals. We can restate this problem as finding the interval around x where : $$g(x) = \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ is constant. I was able to discover through empirical methods that for a given value $x^*$, lower bound is:
$$x^* - \frac{(ax^*+b) mod (cx^*+d)}{a - cg(x^*)}$$

I also discovered an upper bound which is approximately $$x^* + \frac{cx^*-((ax^*+b) mod (cx^*+d))}{a - cg(x^*)}$$ although you adjust upward by some small number $n$ depending on certain conditions.

I coded these up and picked quite a few random coefficient and large ranges, and these formulas held true throughout my testing.

However, I'm quite interested in how we could derive such formulas, and prove they're correct. Based on how I discovered the lower bound and the insights along the way, I'm fairly certain there's a way to prove that it's correct. Likewise with upper bound, the one I found it so complicated that there must be a more elegant way of expressing it.

If you can think of anyway to solve the initial problem more elegantly, totally open to suggestions on that too :).

Comment: In the end it must reduce to $\,\left\lfloor \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \right\rfloor = n \;\iff\; n \le \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \lt n+1\,$ where $\,n=g(x^*)\,$ though I haven't followed all the other steps through.

Comment: Forgive me if this is clear, but what has this to do with group theory?

Comment: Editted to remove group theory, added by mistake.

Comment: @dxiv I tried this method, and it works. Thanks a ton. Now that I see how this I'm super disappointed I didn't see it myself, much simpler than the formula I got.

Comment: @sprw121 Glad it helped. It is perfectly fine, even encouraged, that you post a self-answer with the details.

Comment: @dxiv solution is trivial, take each side of the inequality and solve for x to get lower and upper bound. add one to the bottom if the remainder is not zero, subtract one from the top if it's remainder is zero.

Comment: I do note that the inequality method and the method I mention share a demoninator, formula in the OP must reduce to the same. Not familiar enough with modular arithmetic to do this analysis though